# How to pass methods into an open SQL connection

Tags: c#, using, sqlconnection

I want to execute methods within a Sql Connection. I want to use the C# "using" object since it makes the connection safe.

The reason I want to execute queries in this way is so I can reuse this connection and build the queries in a separate class/location.

```
class foo 
{  

 public void connectionMethod()  
    {  
        using(SqlConnection aConnection=new SqlConnection('ConnectionString')  
        {
            //Query here.
        }  
    }  
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: with the using statment how can you reuse the connection for each call. Did you mean to pass the query as a paramanter and reuse the function as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class you where you want to build your queries, declare each method to accept a `SqlConnection` parameter.

```
// query method
public void SomeQuery(SqlConnection connection)
{
    ...
}


// use it
using(SqlConnection aConnection=new SqlConnection('ConnectionString')  
{
     aConnection.Open();
     otherClass.SomeQuery(aConnection);
}
```

Passing a parameter will create a copy of the reference to the `SqlConnection` object which will be in scope within the called method. Make sure you don't leak it outside the method though.

Comment: Don't all of those methods still need to be within the scope of the "using" statement? I'm looking for a way to pass them into that using statement.

Comment: Passing a parameter will create a copy of the reference which will be in scope within the called method. Make sure you don't leak it outside the method though.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was making this more complicated than it needed to be!